# Find unique elements from first array not repeated in second array using js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays

```
array1 = ["ab", "xyz", "qr", "pqrs"]
array2 = ["ab", "def", "lmno", "def", "qr", "pqrs"]
```

how to compare these two arrays and get a third array of the element from first array which is not found in second array.

Desired result:

```
unique = ["xyz"]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: @str the question u posted is using jquery and i needed a solution with javascript.

Comment: But the answers do not (at least not all of them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution using `Array#filter`.

```js
var array1 = ["ab", "xyz", "qr", "pqrs"],
    array2 = ["ab", "def", "lmno", "def", "qr", "pqrs"],
    unique = array1.filter(v => array2.indexOf(v) == -1);
    
    console.log(unique);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.filter`.

Here in this snippet, it checks whether every element of `array1` is part of `array2` using `filter` and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
var array1 = ["ab", "xyz", "qr", "pqrs"]
var array2 = ["ab", "def", "lmno", "def", "qr", "pqrs"]

var unique = array1.filter(cur => !array2.includes(cur))
console.log(unique)
```

Comment: @downvoter, what's wrong with this answer?